# Table width exceeds the page width

Tags: tables

I have created a table but the table width is extending beyond the page.

The code for the table is this

```
\begin{table}[]
  \centering
   \caption{My caption}
   \label{my-label}
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
   \hline
   Competentie beschrijving & Bekwaamheidseisen: de student & Sterk & Zwak \\ \hline
   \multirow{4}{*}{Competent in, zelfreflectie en ontwikkeling} & kan kritisch, reflecteren op zichzelf. &  &  \\ \cline{2-4} 
   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}kan eigen ontwikkeling mondeling en\\ schriftelijk onder woorden brengen.\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{2-4} 
   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}kan een\\ gesprek voeren over eigen, of andermans levensvragen (geluk, rouw, identiteit,\\ zingeving, etc.).\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{2-4} 
   & kan aan de hand,van een casus in het practicum zijn/haar eigen levensbeschouwing koppelen aan,het professionele handelen. &  &  \\ \hline
   &  &  &  \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And the table looks like this. How can I fit the table to the width of the page. 
[image: table]
PS: It is supposed to be a table that is a couple of pages long. Don't know if there is a package or anything that is better for tables. I have tried tabularx but still the table was to wide.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  it would be easier to answer this if you expanded the code to begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` so that potential assistants can just copy and paste a compilable example for experimentation.  (different "initial conditions" can have drastically different outcomes, so it's often wasted time trying to devise an answer based on incomplete information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. I added  `makecell` to give cells some padding, vial `\setcellgapes{...}\makegapedcells`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, dutch]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ltablex, multirow, makecell, caption}

\begin{document}

\keepXColumns\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{25mm}|*{3}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}}
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label} \\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \tablename \thetable. My caption (continued) \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize (To be continued)}
  \endfoot
  \hline
  \endlastfoot
  Competentie beschrijving & Bekwaamheidseisen: de student & Sterk & Zwak \\ \hline
  \multirow{18}{=}{Competent in, zelfreflectie en ontwikkeling} & kan kritisch, reflecteren op zichzelf. & & \\ \cline{2-4}
                                                                & kan eigen ontwikkeling mondeling en schriftelijk onder woorden brengen. & & \\ \cline{2-4}
                                                                & kan een gesprek voeren over eigen, of andermans levensvragen (geluk, rouw, identiteit, zingeving, etc.). & & \\ \cline{2-4}
                                                                & kan aan de hand,van een casus in het practicum zijn/haar eigen levensbeschouwing koppelen aan,het professionele handelen. & &
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really need is a `longtable` environment. Assuming the four columns should be equally wide, the following code may be the way to go. (Note that I would also strongly suggest that you give the table a much more open look by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e,booktabs}
% compute usable column width (4 columns in table)
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\textwidth-6\tabcolsep\relax}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{0.25\mylen}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}YYYY@{}}

% headers and footers:
\caption{My caption} \label{my-label}\\
\toprule
Competentie beschrijving & Bekwaamheidseisen: de student & Sterk & Zwak \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Table \ref{my-label}, cont'd}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
Competentie beschrijving & Bekwaamheidseisen: de student & Sterk & Zwak \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{continued on following page}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

% body of longtable:
Competent in, zelfreflectie en ontwikkeling 
  & kan kritisch, reflecteren op zichzelf. 
  & 
  &  \\ 
\addlinespace % use whitespace, not '\cline{2-4}'
  & kan eigen ontwikkeling mondeling en schriftelijk onder woorden brengen. 
  & 
  &  \\ 
\addlinespace 
  & kan een gesprek voeren over eigen, of andermans levensvragen (geluk, rouw, identiteit, zingeving, etc.). 
  & 
  &  \\ 
\addlinespace 
  & kan aan de hand,van een casus in het practicum zijn\slash haar eigen levensbeschouwing koppelen aan,het professionele handelen. 
  & 
  &  \\ 

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't know this existed.